# Ubuntu 16.04 - fatal error: No such file or directory (dnet.h & daq.h)

Tags: 16.04

I have snort 16.04 and trying to install barnyard2.

When I am trying to run make command I got the next errors:

**fatal error: daq.h: No such file or directory**

**fatal error: dnet.h: No such file or directory**

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/firnsy/barnyard2/issues/133) help?

Comment: @dragosht, Nope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the next commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libdaq-dev
apt-get install libdumbnet-dev
```

And run make command again.

Comment: Working, Thanks a lot!